# Legend formatting in matlab plot doesn't work

Tags: python, matplotlib

Learning Python as an alternative to Excel. Was feeling quite proud of myself having constructed a pivot table and drawn a chart in just a day. But I can't move the legend on the chart. I've read the Matlab documentation and various other examples 50 times so time to ask.

1. What is wrong with the code?
2. How do I tell python/matlab to keep using the default column headings for the legend but simply to be outside the X axis?

Code is:

```
my_plot = windtable.plot(kind='line')
my_plot.set_title("Wind Power")
my_plot.set_ylabel("MW")
my_plot.set_xlabel("Time of day")
my_plot.legend('NSW','QLD','SA','TAS','VIC','Location','southoutside')
```

returns the chart with default legend and a type error

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

----> 5 my_plot.legend('NSW','QLD','SA','TAS','VIC','Location','southoutside', 'Orientation','horizontal')....TypeError: legend only accepts two non-keyword arguments

I've tried a lot of variations including assigning the legend to a variable, using a with statement, but no go.

Comment: Can we see how your plot looks if you replace the last line by `my_plot.legend()`?

Answer (score 1):

Two things are going on here.

First, to assign values to a legend, they need to be passed as a list (it is not clear from your example but I guess you have 5 lines, from NSW to VIC).

Second, you want the location of your legend to be outside of the axes. To do so, you can use a combination of *loc* and *bbox_to_anchor* properties, like that:

```py
my_plot.set_title("Wind Power")
my_plot.set_ylabel("MW")
my_plot.set_xlabel("Time of day")
my_plot.legend(
    ['NSW','QLD','SA','TAS','VIC'],
    loc='center left',
    bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5)
)
```

This is what I get on my test dataframe:

[image]

Comment: Ilya, thank you but that doesn't work. Python no longer reports an error but neither does it move the legend. Its as if it ignores the my_plot.legend command entirely and simply uses the default settings.